# Xam.Plugins.Notifier: Android Tap in Xamarin.Forms.Shell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, notifications, xamarin.shell

Using Xam.Plugins.Notifier for Local Notifications I am able to show a notification in Android. However, when I tap the notification, it reloads the application. Similar to how a remote notification would.

I handle the OnNewIntent() in the MainActivitiy.cs but it never fires.

How do I tap a Local Notification made by Xam.Plugins.Notifier so that OnNewIntent() fires and I can show a Shell item?

```
protected async override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
    if (title != null)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Tools/Sales");
    }
}
```

I have a SplashScreen Activity that actually starts the app:

How do I pass the Intent that starts the activity to the MainActitity from the Splash

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed() { }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `MainActivty` class, set its `LaunchMode` to `SingleTop` so the OS will reuse the activity IF it is all already running vs. starting a new one:

```
[Activity(Label = "Your Xamarin Forms App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
```

**NOTE**: There are two entry points into `MainActvity` for the notification intent

a. If the activity is already running, `OnNewIntent` will be called with the intent that you setup on the notification.

b. If your app is not running, `MainActvity` will be created as a normal startup but will include the intent from from the notification, so check the intent in the OnCreate.

Comment: I edited my question, I have a SplashActivity that kicks off the app - I need to pass the Intent forward?

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com You could....it depends on your use-case, for me, I would want to skip the splash screen and tag the MainActivity as the singletop and use a MainActivity intent for the notification (personally I would not use a separate splash screen via an activity on an Android app and instead set a background drawable via a drawable resource on the app's window and reset it after the app is init'd via  Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource, app startup is faster and it avoids issues like the notification intent, etc... Even Google recommends not using a separate actvity anymore)